# IE8 Compatibilty issues

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser

How to handle IE8 compatibility issues?
Please let me know if anyone has faced this problem and has some solutions.

Comment: Yes! People have been known to encounter Web browser compatibility issues ;-)  Pardon the kind sarcasm, I'd just wanted to inject a bit of humour on a painful subject.  On a serious note, you should be more specific about your situation, about the particular type of compatibility problems, etc. so that people know how to address your concerns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is such a vague question as to be almost unanswerable, but here are some approaches.

IE8 introduces a meta tag that you can place in your `<head>` element:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7">
```

There are also a number of tools that you can employ to help diagnose layout and rendering problems, such as [Web Expression SuperPreview](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/default.aspx#a4c137983-38f7-42cb-a4c1-6d2512be9125).

Finally, don't forget to take advantage of the IE8 Developer Tools.  They get overshadowed by Firebug much of the time, but they are still quite powerful and provide some good insight into debugging your sites.

As a final word, I would suggest that in IE8, assuming your HTML and (especially) your CSS is valid (css 2.1), then the problem is likely not an IE8 compatibility issue as it is another version's problem.

Answer (score 2):

If your page works okay in IE7, you can use this metatag to tell IE8 to render and behave like IE7:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" >
```

There are other modes available if this one is not enough to meet your needs, you can even tell it to render like IE5: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: This is not always the best solution.  IE8 generally renders sites more correctly than previous versions.  While adding the meta tag will likely mask the problem, the likelihood is that you will still have an underlying issue that may affect other browser flavours.

Comment: It's just a stopgap, hopefully no one is considering this a permanent fix.